# In Armature, how do I "merge" two "bone roots"

Tags: rigging

I don't know how to explain this better, check this image:

[image]

In this image, every bone goes to the pivot BUT they do NOT share the root point: each bone has its own, even though to generate them, I selected the first one and hit Extrude to make them.

As you can see here, the bones each have its own root point:

[image]

Is it possible to connect them all to a single one?
I couldn't find this info anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

No, Bones cannot share a root. I found this out the hard way. You can parent all the bones to one parent, and thus have their roots together.

If you are encountering this situation on the hips of a humanoid, the standard practice is to simply parent the upper leg bones (which point downward) to the bottom spine bone (which points upward) without connecting them (I.e. choosing “keep offset”).

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will simply find a configuration to make it work starting from the second bone...